# LEX replacement for Delete override that only applies to UI-initiated delete action?

Tags: delete, button-overrides

As prep for migrating to LEX, we need to replace our existing Delete overrides for Quote and QuoteLineItem; they check a custom setting and a couple fields and determine if delete should be allowed.

The problem with just moving the logic to a trigger (which seems to be the typical approach) is that then it will be applied not only to a user clicking Delete in the UI (which is the only place we want to run these checks), but to so many other potential causes for the delete, like some or all of the following:

- trigger from another record
- flow and process builder
- cascade delete
- data loader
- etc

Approaches we've considered:

1. Taking delete CRUD away from users that shouldn't have it. Unfortunately you only need edit on Quote to be able to delete QuoteLineItems, and it doesn't allow for the additional validation we do.
2. Moving the logic to a trigger and implementing something like a trigger-depth tracker (just a class with a counter that is incremented upon entering any trigger, and decremented upon exiting). The idea being that if the counter is at 1, then the current trigger is the entry point so do run the validation. The problem with that is that it doesn't account for deleting a Quote or QLI that is initiated from flow, process builder, dataloader, etc. I can think of a mish-mash of ways to allow for all of that, but the result would be complex, hard to maintain, and risky.
3. Replace the places in the UI where Delete is surfaced with custom implementation that does the validation: replace default Delete button with custom VF button, replace Related Lists with custom component, etc. But Delete is also surfaced on List Views and we can't realistically prevent that.

Am I missing some magical way to solve this problem that allows you to intercept (or identify) Delete only when it has been executed through the UI? Or some way in code to identify the initial entry point as coming from the UI?